# Specifying an alternate manifest.json location in OpenUI5

Tags: cordova, config, sapui5

Is there a way to specify the location of the manifest.json file in OpenUI5 / SAPUI5?

I'm deploying an app in Cordova and would like a way to update the application config by reading the manifest.json file from another location. Our manifest.json specifies environment URLs. Copying a file over is simpler than having to re-package and redeploy if we need to change the environment.

Am I going about this the wrong way?  Any suggestions on a better way to change environment parameters without redeploying?  Application runs on both iOS and Android.

Comment: One idea: Make a JSON service that delivers the environment URLS > Setup your models that depend on the environment URLs in your Component.js (which ideally will be called after your manifest file has been loaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of [ComponentMetadata](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.38/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/ComponentMetadata.js#L93) it seems like you can either set the manifest to be loaded from the default location

```js
metadata: {
   manifest: "json"
}
```

or supply the actual manifest as javascript object.

```js
metadata: {
   manifest: {
    "sap.app": {
      "type": "component",
      "i18n": "resources/i18n/texts.properties",
      "title": "Bla",
      "description": "Blabla",
      "applicationVersion": {
        "version": "1.0.0"
      },
      "dataSources": {
      }
   }
}
```

You could use that to load the manifest from a non default location and assign the deserialized json.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @schnoedel for giving me this idea.  What I eventually did was load a json config file and attach to the global model.  I was able to access the config file on the native file system by using a cdvfile:// url.

```
if(Device.os.ios) {
  oModel.loadData('cdvfile://localhost/library/Preferences/config.json','',true,'GET',true);
} else {
  oModel.loadData('cdvfile://localhost/documents/config.json','',true,'GET',true);
}

this.setModel(tModel);
```

This code is in the Component.js init function.  It seems that setting the model here makes it global throughout your app.